# Returnsasync(null) throws a build error when using Moq for unit testing in VS15

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

When I use `ReturnsAsync(null)` in a C# unit test method in Visual Studio (with `Moq`), I get the error:

> "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"

and then a list of the `ReturnsAsync` methods which have different parameters.  I understand that this is due to the `ReturnsAsync` function being overloaded.  However, when I run the same unit test on my colleague's computer, it runs without any errors.  Does anyone know why this would happen?  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also, when I build, I get warnings that:

> all packages referencing ******** must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl.Build.

Could that have any effect?

Comment: It's completely OK to use `ReturnAsync(null)`. Check methods with ambiguous call - where these methods defined.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it says the ReturnsAsync method has an ambiguous call when null is a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you already stated that in question

Comment: What methods should I check then?  All the overloaded returnasync methods?

Comment: All overloaded methods with single parameter. Can you give us signatures of those methods?

Comment: This is the error message: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>>, TResult)' and 'ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>>, Func<TResult>)'

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There are two `ReturnsAsync` extension methods in Moq `ReturnsExtensions` class.They have following parameters:

```
(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, TResult value)
(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, Func<TResult> valueFunction)
```

As you can see one accepts value which should be returned by task, and another accepts delegate which will return value. When you are passing `null` compiler don't know whether it value or delegate. It's not the case when task parameter is a value type (e.g. int). Because it cannot be null and compiler understands that null is a delegate. Probably that's the case with your colleague's computer.

To fix this error you need to help compiler choose correct method overload - cast null to type of task's result (e.g. string):

```
RetursAsync((string)null)
```

Or you can pass value which is null

```
string s = null;
... ReturnsAsync(s);
```

Comment: alternatively you could pass

    `RetursAsync(default(string))`

Comment: Or, if you have lots of these errors after an upgrade and don't want to bother casting to different return types: `ReturnsAsync(() => null)`

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that the **compiler is choosing which overloaded method to call based on the type of method's parameters and the type of parameters being passed**. It's called **method overload resolution**. But the [literal `null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null) means "*without a value*" and, at the same time, it doesn't itself carry any type information. And without the type, the compiler doesn't know which overloaded method to call, so it complains that the "*call is ambiguous*".

If you would pass the literal `"Hello world"` instead of `null`, you (the compiler) know that it has a value (the text "Hello world") and it's the `string` type. But in case of `null`, the type information is missing – it may be a string without a value, a delegate without a value or for example a custom reference type without a value.

As [Sergey mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637268/971141), there are two overloaded methods:

```
(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, TResult value)
(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, Func<TResult> valueFunction)
```

They both have a single parameter, the first one of type `TResult` and the second one of type `Func<TResult>`. The `null` without a type information may be both/any of them, so you just need to hint the compiler which one to call.

You have two options:

- link the `null` value to some type and call the overload accepting `TResult`
- pass a function returning the `null`, i.e. call the overload accepting `Func<TResult>`

For me, the easiest solution was to wrap the `null` into a function, so I didn't have to worry about types anymore. I simply passed an [expression lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#expression-lambdas) returning `null` as the parameter, that means I have used the second overloaded method accepting a delegate `Func<TResult>`:

```
ReturnAsync(() => null)
```

On the other side, as Sergey mentioned, you can assign the `null` into a typed variable and pass that:

```
string x = null;
‪….ReturnAsync(x);
```

That way, you have linked the `null` with a particular type, a string in this case, so again, the compiler will know which overload to use.

Answer (score 1):

Example how to pass value explicitly

```
GetTokenClient.Setup(e =>
    e.GetToken(It.IsAny<GetTokenParams>(),It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
).ReturnsAsync(
    (GetTokenParams GetTokenParams, CancellationToken CancellationToken) => 
        new BaseResult<GetTokenResult>() { IsSuccess = true }
);
```